# Pass Javascript variable within the HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm try to pass the value of a VARIABLE from the Javascript to the iframe statement within the same HTML file.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var videourl =  playerurl.substring(0,36);  
</script>

<iframe width="420" height="345"
src="videourl">
</iframe>
```

Just want to pass the value in the variable "videourl" into the iframe statement src= and I just don't know what is the right synax for it.

Thanks,

Comment: You forgot the `>` behind "text/javascript"

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName ("iframe") [0].src = videourl;

Answer (score 0):

Add an `id` to your `iframe`

```
<iframe width="420" height="345"
     id="myframe">
</iframe>
```

then do

```
document.getElementById("myframe").src=videourl;
```

Your final result should be

```
<iframe width="420" height="345"
    id="myframe">
</iframe>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var videourl =  playerurl.substring(0,36);  
document.getElementById("myframe").src=videourl;
</script>
```

Comment: how to get id to the iframe?

Comment: @user1985788 Look at the html I add where `id="myframe"`.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how can I only show th iframe if it is mobile devices?

Comment: @user1985788 CSS media queries would be your best bet. Google and/or the StackOverflow site search should provide you with some information on how to use them.